# Uploading Attachments to QuickBooks Online Api - PHP

Tags: php, curl, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm using [Quickbooks Integration Lib](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php), it fulfills all of my requirement but there are no examples for this library to upload attachments to QuickBooks,
somebody has already raise an [issue](http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8261) but no solution for this bug.

But I've tried a bit by setting via some curl options like below to upload files

Request (set via curl params):

```
Array
(
    [47] => 1
    [10015] => 
        --d6c3e579ddbcf4333df36c1efc0d60ce
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_metadata_0"
        Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <ns0:Attachable xmlns:ns0="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
          <ns0:AttachableRef>
            <ns0:EntityRef type="Invoice">190</ns0:EntityRef>
          </ns0:AttachableRef>
          <ns0:FileName>7374.jpg</ns0:FileName>
          <ns0:Category>Image</ns0:Category>
          <ns0:Tag>Tag_7374</ns0:Tag>
        </ns0:Attachable>
        --d6c3e579ddbcf4333df36c1efc0d60ce
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_0"; filename="7374.jpg"
        Content-Type: image/jpeg
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

        /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAlgCWAAD/4ge4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAeoYXBwbAIgAABtbnRyUkdC
        IFhZWiAH2QACABkACwAaAAthY3NwQVBQTAAAAABhcHBsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAA
        AADTLWFwcGwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtk
        ZXNjAAABCAAAAG9kc2NtAAABeAAABWxjcHJ0AAAG5AAAADh3dHB0AAAHHAAAABRyWFlaAAAHMAAA
        ABRnWFlaAAAHRAAAABRiWFlaAAAHWAAAABRyVFJDAAAHbAAAAA5jaGFkAAAHfAAAACxiVFJDAAAH
        bAAAAA5nVFJDAAAHbAAAAA5kZXNjAAAAAAAAABRHZW5lcmljIFJHQiBQcm9maWxlAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AAAUR2VuZXJpYyBSR0IgUHJvZmlsZQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbWx1YwAAAAAAAAAeAAAADHNrU0sAAAAoAAABeGhySFIAAAAoAAABoGNh
        RVMAAAAkAAAByHB0QlIAAAAmAAAB7HVrVUEAAAAqAAACEmZyRlUAAAAoAAACPHpoVFcAAAAWAAAC
        ZGl0SVQAAAAoAAACem5iTk8AAAAmAAAComtvS1IAAAAWAAACyGNzQ1oAAAAiAAAC3mhlSUwAAAAe
        AAADAGRlREUAAAAsAAADHmh1SFUAAAAoAAADSnN2U0UAAAAmAAAConpoQ04AAAAWAAADcmphSlAA
        AAAaAAADiHJvUk8AAAAkAAADomVsR1IAAAAiAAADxnB0UE8AAAAmAAAD6G5sTkwAAAAoAAAEDmVz
        RVMAAAAmAAAD6HRoVEgAAAAkAAAENnRyVFIAAAAiAAAEWmZpRkkAAAAoAAAEfHBsUEwAAAAsAAAE
        pHJ1UlUAAAAiAAAE0GFyRUcAAAAmAAAE8mVuVVMAAAAmAAAFGGRhREsAAAAuAAAFPgBWAWEAZQBv
        AGIAZQBjAG4A/QAgAFIARwBCACAAcAByAG8AZgBpAGwARwBlAG4AZQByAGkBDQBrAGkAIABSAEcA
        QgAgAHAAcgBvAGYAaQBsAFAAZQByAGYAaQBsACAAUgBHAEIAIABnAGUAbgDoAHIAaQBjAFAAZQBy
        AGYAaQBsACAAUgBHAEIAIABHAGUAbgDpAHIAaQBjAG8EFwQwBDMEMAQ7BEwEPQQ4BDkAIAQ/BEAE
        PgREBDAEOQQ7ACAAUgBHAEIAUAByAG8AZgBpAGwAIABnAOkAbgDpAHIAaQBxAHUAZQAgAFIAVgBC
        kBp1KAAgAFIARwBCACCCcl9pY8+P8ABQAHIAbwBmAGkAbABvACAAUgBHAEIAIABnAGUAbgBlAHIA
        aQBjAG8ARwBlAG4AZQByAGkAcwBrACAAUgBHAEIALQBwAHIAbwBmAGkAbMd8vBgAIABSAEcAQgAg
        1QS4XNMMx3wATwBiAGUAYwBuAP0AIABSAEcAQgAgAHAAcgBvAGYAaQBsBeQF6AXVBeQF2QXcACAA
        UgBHAEIAIAXbBdwF3AXZAEEAbABsAGcAZQBtAGUAaQBuAGUAcwAgAFIARwBCAC0AUAByAG8AZgBp
        AGwAwQBsAHQAYQBsAOEAbgBvAHMAIABSAEcAQgAgAHAAcgBvAGYAaQBsZm6QGgAgAFIARwBCACBj
        z4/wZYdO9k4AgiwAIABSAEcAQgAgMNcw7TDVMKEwpDDrAFAAcgBvAGYAaQBsACAAUgBHAEIAIABn
        AGUAbgBlAHIAaQBjA5MDtQO9A7kDugPMACADwAPBA78DxgOvA7sAIABSAEcAQgBQAGUAcgBmAGkA
        bAAgAFIARwBCACAAZwBlAG4A6QByAGkAYwBvAEEAbABnAGUAbQBlAGUAbgAgAFIARwBCAC0AcABy
        AG8AZgBpAGUAbA5CDhsOIw5EDh8OJQ5MACAAUgBHAEIAIA4XDjEOSA4nDkQOGwBHAGUAbgBlAGwA
        IABSAEcAQgAgAFAAcgBvAGYAaQBsAGkAWQBsAGUAaQBuAGUAbgAgAFIARwBCAC0AcAByAG8AZgBp
        AGkAbABpAFUAbgBpAHcAZQByAHMAYQBsAG4AeQAgAHAAcgBvAGYAaQBsACAAUgBHAEIEHgQxBEkE
        OAQ5ACAEPwRABD4ERAQ4BDsETAAgAFIARwBCBkUGRAZBACAGKgY5BjEGSgZBACAAUgBHAEIAIAYn
        BkQGOQYnBkUARwBlAG4AZQByAGkAYwAgAFIARwBCACAAUAByAG8AZgBpAGwAZQBHAGUAbgBlAHIA
        ZQBsACAAUgBHAEIALQBiAGUAcwBrAHIAaQB2AGUAbABzAGV0ZXh0AAAAAENvcHlyaWdodCAyMDA3
        IEFwcGxlIEluYy4sIGFsbCByaWdodHMgcmVzZXJ2ZWQuAFhZWiAAAAAAAADzUgABAAAAARbPWFla
        IAAAAAAAAHRNAAA97gAAA9BYWVogAAAAAAAAWnUAAKxzAAAXNFhZWiAAAAAAAAAoGgAAFZ8AALg2
        Y3VydgAAAAAAAAABAc0AAHNmMzIAAAAAAAEMQgAABd7///MmAAAHkgAA/ZH///ui///9owAAA9wA
        AMBs/+EAgEV4aWYAAE1NACoAAAAIAAUBEgADAAAAAQABAAABGgAFAAAAAQAAAEoBGwAFAAAAAQAA
        AFIBKAADAAAAAQACAACHaQAEAAAAAQAAAFoAAAAAAAA6mQAAAGQAADqZAAAAZAACoAIABAAAAAEA
        AAAuoAMABAAAAAEAAAAUAAAAAP/bAEMAAgEBAgEBAgIBAgICAgIDBQMDAwMDBgQEAwUHBgcHBwYG
        BgcICwkHCAoIBgYJDQkKCwsMDAwHCQ0ODQwOCwwMC//bAEMBAgICAwIDBQMDBQsIBggLCwsLCwsL
        CwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLC//AABEIABQALgMBIgAC
        EQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAAA
        AX0BAgMABBEFEiExQQYTUWEHInEUMoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzYnKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4
        OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaan
        qKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/xAAfAQAD
        AQEBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEG
        EkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpT
        VFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqCg4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4
        ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2dri4+Tl5ufo6ery8/T19vf4+fr/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APkb41eO
        NYtfi94oSDVdRVF1a74FzJgfvn96j+Kmj+O/gj/wj3/C159Q0MeK9Et/EekmfU1IvdPuN/kzrtkO
        0N5b/K2GGOQKzvjnz8YPFX/YVvP/AEc9fePiv9qXwn4K+Eut674A8S+Br3xl4e/Zd8MaZ4dF0LPU
        HtvENte3TtbwwThla8h3RuYipI+UspFfueIryw6p8kOa+n5Ja62310Z+V4XDRxU5RlPl8z4O0S/8
        YeJfB+t+IfD1xrN7oPhpbZtV1GG7ZrXTxczeRb+bJvwDLLlEAyWYHA4OK/hTxP4i8ceKdI0Xwrq9
        1eanr13FY6fANS2fappZFjRVdnCgF2UFiQozkkDmv0r+KX7VPhO/8JftJaX8I/HPwu0qXxf4c8C+
        JZIA1hDb63cpldfjtwI2WS7NvFGnkINyyMpXY7Fqq/GDUvhB4d+IXxP17TPHvwc1nTfiB8a/h/4o
        0O10zVbW4lstChubNbxpoto+zxARztLHyAgZnADc8NPN5ydpUbXtbfqob6dOZ9vha8zu/smElpXX
        W+3eW2vku+5+fXjvw38RPhlZm58eRa7ptp/a97oCXT3m+3nv7Jtt3BDKkhWUwtwzISgPG4mux/ZD
        8Y6tefEO++06nqL7dOkxm6k4/exf7VfRX/BRD9oTTfiz+xBaaD8NPGfgK803wz8XvFf2nRLOWzjv
        30+XU5pNKntIUQSPbeU+8yxkKUK7i+AB8x/sc/8AJQ7/AP7Bz/8Ao2KuqlWnicLOdSKTu1b0em/d
        anFVpRw+IjCnK60d/X0O/wDil+zfoWofE7xJNcXOqb31W7JxJHj/AF7/APTOsH/hmPw//wA/Gqf9
        /I//AI3RRXRTk+VamM4rmegv/DMfh/H/AB8ap/38j/8AjdB/Zj8Pn/l41Trn/WR9f+/dFFVzPuRZ
        XEP7Mfh89bjVOP8AppFx/wCQ69I/Zf8A2d9F0z4hXP2S61Qb9Olzl4z0lh/6Z+9FFY4mT9lLU1oJ
        c6P/2Q==

        --d6c3e579ddbcf4333df36c1efc0d60ce--
    [19913] => 1
    [10002] => https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/PASSING_REALM_ID/upload?minorversion=2
    [10023] => Array
        (
            [0] => Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d6c3e579ddbcf4333df36c1efc0d60ce
            [1] => Authorization: OAuth realm="", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="gnC4JlTG30UuvBIbhJSw2akChlY%3D",  oauth_nonce="EHXw9", oauth_timestamp="1447127370", oauth_token="OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_consumer_key="OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_version="1.0"
            [2] => Content-Length: 5653
        )

    [10102] => 
    [41] => 
    [42] => 1
    [64] => 
    [81] => 0
)
```

Response:

```
message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401
```

Rest of stuffs like adding invoice working fine, getting error for only this request.
I've gone through what this error code [003200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891385/quickbooks-ipp-v3-getting-error-3200-when-adding-invoice), several times i disconnected app and connected but no use, it still gives me the above error

Could you guys help me to fix this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?

Comment: I'm unable to upload attachment using Consolibyte php plugin, but Official Quickbooks PHP SDK can able to do that, you can check here https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0005_sdks/0209_php/0002_install_the_php_sdk